# Replay Buffer taking long time to construct (Reinforcement Learning DQN with tf-agetns)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorflow, dqn

I'm new to Reinforcement Learning and I have some question. I am actually training some DQN using the tf-agents from tensorflow. And I recently learned that it's not possible to train a DQN using continuous actions. So the continuous actions that I had had, well I just converted that to discrete actions.

So now, it's about to set up my replay buffer (note I haven't started the actual training part yet, but just setting up the buffer. But I notice that it's taking up a long time than usual. Initially, I had a 0-1 action space and the replay buffer construction was quick. But then I realized I was missing something in my action space that I had to convert it from a discrete to a continuous action space from [0,1]. But when I realized that training DQN with continuous action space is not possible (and that the replay buffer is taking very long to construct), I reverted back to discrete space with min action value of 0 and max action value of M, for some integer M (but now it's action space is discrete and yet it is still taking time in the construction of the replay buffer).

So I am not sure what's going on here? Why is my replay buffer taking a long time to work? Does that have to do with my action space? My integer M is a parameter, but I'm testing it on a data with an M value of 4,235. So that means the action space has 4,236 possible actions. Could it be the reason that it's taking long is I have so many actions?

```
replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
                                data_spec=agent.collect_data_spec,                                                                
                                batch_size=tf_env.batch_size,                                                              
                                max_length=100000)
```